Hat knot Floer Homology with Z coefficients calculation
I would like to ask for recommended references which carry out the calculation of the hat knot Floer homology of a knot with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients, i.e., $\widehat{\operatorname{HFK}}(K;\mathbb{Z})$, where the differentials $\partial$ are not all zero.
In particular, I am looking for a hands-on assignment of orientations to moduli spaces leading to a computation of homology with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients.
Such orientation assignment is at least abstractly defined in Definition 3.11/3.12, p.29 of Ozsváth and Szabó - Holomorphic disks and topological invariants for closed three-manifolds (for Heegaard Floer homology, though I think it should apply to knot Floer as well). The analytic approach to orientation (trivialization of virtual index bundle) is good for certain things, but I feel it's not helpful for computations.
